# Migrating Data as Part of Database Migration

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-migrations

I have an EFCore project that has an existing table with some data in it. I'd like to create a new table, transfer some data from the existing table and then remove some columns from the existing table. A simple example would be:

A user class with address and city fields:

```
public class User
{
   long ID {get;set;}
   string UserName {get; set;}
   string Password {get; set;}
   string StreetAddress {get; set;}
   string City {get; set;}
}
```

And lets say later on I wanted to allow for a user to have multiple addresses so I create an Address object

```
public class Address
{
   long ID {get; set;}
   long UserId{get; set;}
   string StreetAddress {get; set;}
   string City {get; set;}   
}
```

I would want to generate a migration to get the StreetAddress and City from users then create a new Address record tied to that user. I would then want to drop the StreetAddress and City fields from User.

My thought was ideally I would be able to do this inside a migration using a combination of MigrationBuilder methods and queries via my projects DatabaseContext.. something like

```
public partial class AddressMigration: Migration
{
  protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
  {
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
      name "Address",
      columns: table => new
      {
         //table columns
      },
      constraints: table =>
      {
       //constraints   
    });
    List<User> users = myContext.Users.ToList();
    foreach(var user in users)
    {
      var address = new Address() 
      {
        UserId = user.id, 
        StreetAddress = user.StreetAddress, 
        City = user.City
      };
      myContext.Addresses.Add(address);
    }
    myContext.SaveChanges();

    migrationBuilder.DropColumn("StreetAddress", table:"User")
  }
}
```

**However** when I start digging around I'm not seeing a way to access the database context inside a migration. I'm seeing in the documentation that I could implement a [custom migration operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/operations) that I could pass parameters to but that would still require me to be able to get the data in the first place.. which I'm unsure how to do. Also it would require raw sql for pretty standard operations which strikes me as an odd thing for a ORM to require.

Could anyone suggest the proper way to do a data migration in ef core? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks much!

Comment: Currently there is no proper way. Odd or not, EFC ORM requires raw SQL for that, like `migrationBuilder.Sql`

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks for the response - so even if I did have to user migrationBuilder.Sql I don't see a method on SqlOperation to actually execute and get a return value. How would I be able to get the existing data for User to create the insert statments for Address in a  migration?

Comment: You can use SQL block/batch, or `insert into … select from ..` etc.

Comment: @IvanStoev yes I see that you can use raw sql in `migrationBuilder.Sql` but it returns a `OperationBuilder<IOperation>` which doesn't appear to have an  API that allows execution of the statement and getting a return value. Like I couldn't get the result of `migrationBuild.Sql("Select city from User;")` Forgive me if I'm being dense here but I'm not seeing it

Comment: No problem. You are right, there isn't return value. The whole work should be done in the sql string passed to the `Sql` method. As I mentioned, it doesn't need to be a single `select`. You can use all SQL block constructs - cursors, (temporary) table variables etc.